# Does "refrain" only mean to choose to do or not do something?

Tags: meaning, verbs

[Here](http://www.tehelka.com/story_main50.asp?filename=Op011011proscons.asp) is the place I saw this usage:

> (Paraphrase) Mr. A's refrain that Law L be invoked against dishonest and incompetent legislators presents an interesting case.

My dictionary tells me

> (irrelevant) refrain ~ noun
>    1. the part of a song where a soloist is joined by a group of singers
>
> refrain ~ verb
>    1. resist doing something
>    2. choose not to consume

My understanding tells me that Mr. A obviously wants to invoke Law L against these legislators, but the dictionary tells me that he is resisting it (himself?)

What am I missing here?

Comment: The noun definition isn't irrelevant since the usage of *refrain* you quote is a noun. See @Gnawme's answer. The quote is saying that Mr. (actually Ms.) A presents an interesting case by keeping on insisting that Law L be invoked against the no-good legislators.

Comment: Your first *(part of a song...)* definition is **not** irrelevant. The parts of a song involving a "chorus" are usually the parts regularly repeated, as apparently are Mr A's opinions on subjecting legislators to the rule of law.

Comment: Thanks both of you, now its more clear to me. I never thought the meaning "something which gets repeated in a _song_ " will be relevant in customary usage. @dr65 : its not Ms. but Mr. only, **his** name is Anna (_not_ like Anna Kournikova, but with Indian nasal *NN* accent) and he is a male, patriotic retired soldier who recently brought the Indian Government to make a resolution to pass a Law to setup a body against corruption.

Comment: Sorry!  I am not very well-versed in Indian names, obviously.  I had thought it was your mistake, and now I see it was mine.  That's embarrassing...

Comment: @drɱ65δ : no no!! its not your mistake (and neither it belongs to anyone, if you at all consider it as a mistake) . Its just a communication gap, which can be expanded into the multitude of differences between the cultural and geo-sociological diversities of human life

Comment: @drɱ65δ : and thanks for adding the word paraphrase to my dictionary (usage)

Comment: @Sudhi That's very gracious of you. :)  It's a pleasure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's being used in this sense (from MW Unabridged):

> refrain, noun: a phrase or verse which recurs regularly

Apparently, it's something that this person calls for again and again.

Comment: thanks, I guess I need to update my dict/thesaurus. Is this(usage) common practice? (off topic Q, please ignore : Maybe its not in my Wordnet based thesaurus [Arhta](http://artha.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Features) because the wordnet version used is bit old?

Comment: I see it used this way several times at least.

Comment: Perhaps your Wordnet database is not very large? I subscribe to Merriam-Webster Unabridged (http://unabridged.merriam-webster.com/) and so have access to a larger database. Dictionary.com also has this definition, but you have to wade through the ads...

Answer (score 0):

A refrain is a statement that is often repeated.